# Binding different objects for different TreeView based on same class getting linked

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, 2-way-object-databinding

I am currently having a **class myCommand**

```
class myCommand : INotifyCollectionChanged , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<myFile> subCommand { get; set; }
}
```

I have two TreeView items in my window.
**tvCommandList** which contains all available commands and **tvFinalList** to hold all selected commands.

I used contextmenu to copy the items from **tvCommandList** to **tvFinalList**;
In the mainWindow, I have two ObservableCollection items which are bound to the TreeViewItems.

```
    ObservableCollection<myCommand> cmdlist = null;
    ObservableCollection<myCommand> finallist = null;
```

These are bound to the TreeView in the XAML file.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="styleTemplate" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsInitiallySelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:myCommand}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding subCommand, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>

<TreeView x:Name="tvSendList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding cmdlist}">
<TreeView x:Name="tvRecvList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding finallist}">
```

I copy TreeViewItem from **cmdlist** to **finallist** and edit them for customsing data.
The issue I am facing here is that if I modify an item (Update the **Name** value) in the **finallist**, the **cmdlist** item also gets updated, which 
I am not sure how to go about to resolve this.

I tried moving the ResourceDictionary to each TreeView specifically, but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also clone, i.e. create a copy of, each individual `myFile` object when you create a copy of the collection, e.g.:

```
finalist = new ObservableCollection<myFile>(cmdlist.Select(x => new myFile()
{
    Property1 = x.Property1,
    Property2 = x.Property2
    //copy all property values...
}));
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem for me. Cloning each object while attaching to the second collection fixed the issue.!!